# XNA XML importing 'Cannot find type "Data.CompactLevelMap".'

Tags: xml, import, xna

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace Data
{
    public class CompactLevelMap
    {
        public string name;
        public string species;
        public float weight;
        public int age;
    }
}
```

This is the CompactLevelMap class (it's a temp), in it's own game library project. it is imported correctly into my main game.

This is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<XnaContent>
  <Asset Type="Data.CompactLevelMap"> //The error occurs here
    <name>sdf</name>
    <species>sdf</species>
    <weight>32</weight>
    <age>12</age>
  </Asset>
</XnaContent>
```

The way I load this into the game is

```
CompactLevelMap compactLevel = new CompactLevelMap();

compactLevel = Content.Load<CompactLevelMap>("Level1");
```

I have researched the problem, but I just keep getting more and more confused. Incidentally, if someone could tell me how to export XML files, I would also be grateful.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a reference to the assembly containing `CompactLevelMap` to your *content* project as well, so that `XmlImporter` can find the type. Right click the content project and select "Add Reference" and then the "Project" tab. (The reason you put it in a separate assembly is so you don't create a circular dependency by referencing your main game.)

---

To export XML in this format, you need to use `IntermediateSerializer.Serialize`. The downside is that `IntermediateSerializer` is not part of the XNA Framework, but part of XNA Game Studio - which is not redistributable. So you can't really include it in a game - but maybe in an editor if you make your users also download VC# Express and XNA GS.

It also requires targeting the full .NET 4.0 Framework (rather than the Client Profile).

There is more detail on this topic in [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/11241/288).

Comment: Alright, for the exporting in the map editor, I can just have a copy window that pops up, then they can copy it into a file and save as a XML file.

Comment: @Halleflux You could also open a file stream and pass it to `XmlWriter.Create`?